# Google Apps Script getId() of deepest folder in a path

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a string that looks like this:

```js
2017\S\Smith, John\ProjectID23869
```

The 2017 folder resides in a parent folder, whose id I have.

```js
var parentFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx12345");
```

I need to get the folderId for ProjectID23869, and I think I need to drill down folder by folder rather than simply find by name at the root. We have tens of thousands of folders, and that takes too much time.

I have tried various methods, but cannot seem to get it.

Again, help is great appreciated. You all are awesome.

Comment: Please include methods you have tried in your question, to avoid having them reiterated to you as suggestions.

Comment: If you haven't already, consider using the `searchFolders()` method, called from the deepest folder you have that you know will contain the the desired file, e.g. [`parentFolder.searchFolders("some query string")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFolders(String))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how they perform with your Drive, here are 2 ways:

**Way # 1**

```
DriveApp.getFoldersByName("your folder").next().getId();
```

In this way, you find your folder through all of your files.

**Way # 2**

```
DriveApp.getFolderById("id for folder0")
  .getFoldersByName("folder1").next()
  .getFoldersByName("folder2").next()
  //...
  .getId()
```

Here, the code may run slower depending on your number of files and Google's servers. I recommend you try both and check if performance is an issue. Way #2 always returns only 1 result even if the projectID string is not unique. However, your path string must not contain any mistakes.

With the current code for Way # 2, a possible error is that you will have two folders with the same name and Way # 2 won't default on the right one.

**Code for both ways**

```
function onOpen() { // this is so you can run it from a Spreadsheet menu

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Deepest file")
  .addItem("easyNameFinder", "easyNameFinder") // Way #1
  .addItem("pathFinder", "pathFinder") // Way #2
  .addToUi();

}

function easyNameFinder() { // Way #1

  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  var folderList = []
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {// in case name is not unique
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderList.push(folder.getId() + " in " + folder.getParents().next().getName());
  }
  var id = "See below the " + folderList.length + " folder match(es) for " + name + "\n" + folderList.join("\n");
  Logger.log(id); // view logs with Ctrl + Enter
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(id); // an alert will appear on the active sheet
}

function pathIterator(query, folder) { // The loop for Way #2

  var folders = folder.getFoldersByName(query)
  if (folders.hasNext()) { // unfortunately, there could be more than one child folder with a given name. If that is the case, you will run into problems.
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();
    Logger.log(name) // view logs with Ctrl + Enter in the Script editor
    if (folder) {
      Logger.log("we just found " + name + "!\n")
      return folder
    }; 
  } else return null;
}

function pathFinder() { // Way #2: main function

  var string = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  var array = string.split("\\")
  Logger.log(array);
  var mother = 'YOUR-PARENT-FILE-ID-HERE';
  var mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(mother); 
  var folder = mainFolder;
  var error;

  array.forEach(function(value) {
    var recursion = pathIterator(value, folder)
    if (recursion) {folder = recursion}
    else {
      error = "Could not find folder \"" + value + "\" in " + folder
      Logger.log(error)
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(error);}
  })

  if (error) {
    return; // skipping the code below if some folder went unfound
  }

  var displayString = folder.getId() + "\nis the Id for the folder " + '"' + folder.getName() + '"'
  Logger.log(displayString); // view logs with Ctrl + Enter
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(displayString); // an alert will appear on the active sheet
}
```

Performance through my own 100 folders:

- Way # 1 (easyNameFinder): 0.495 seconds
- Way # 2 (pathFinder): 1.091 seconds

Comment: @tehhowch I wish you were right about getFoldersByName(string), but it is basically the equivalent of Method 1, because it searches through all folders in a user's drive — not through a given folder. Thanks though: I suspect it will be more performant than Method 1. Will edit to include your other advice, too.

Comment: Actually, you seem to be right about all of it @tehhowch

Comment: Google Drive will absolutely let you have multiple folders with the same name and the same parent folder.